# Addition image JSP problem. How to solve it?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a JSP page where I need to add an image, but for some reason it is not displayed

The path to the image looks like this:

D:\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.56\webapps\wtpwebapps\epamtc-final-project-online-shop\productCategoryImg\Vstavlennoe_izobrazhenie_-_11_2.png

```
<c:if test="${ empty exception_msg}">
    <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <a href="">
                <img src="file:///${category.imgPath}" width="200" height="200" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4> 
                ${category.name} 
            </h4> 
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Comment: It used to be possible; not any more

Comment: @MauricePerry what can I do?

Comment: a `file://...` does not make any sense on the client side - perhaps you want something like `src="epamtc-final-project-online-shop/productCategoryImg/Vstavlennoe_izobrazhenie_-_11_2.png"`

Comment: Store file in tomcat instead of Physical path so you can provide dynamic path.